# How to parse a date and time with an ambiguous timezone in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, date, time, timezone

I am using a web service and for the city Florianopolis in Brazil I get the following date:

Tue, 06 Nov 2012 5:30 pm LST

Now the timezone "LST" creates a problem to the SimpleDateFormat parser:

```
// Date to parse
String dateString = "Tue, 06 Nov 2012 5:30 pm LST";

// This parser works with other timezones
SimpleDateFormat LONG_DATE = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy h:mm a zzz");

// Here it throws a ParseException
Date date = LONG_DATE.parse(dateString);
```

I know that the timezones can be difficult to parse. What do you propose?

Thank you

Comment: You can use Joda Time or a four letter timezone instead. Many three letter timezones have multiple meanings. LST can mean Lunar Standard Time, Local Sidereal Time (used in Latvia) or Local Solar Time.

Comment: Peter you are right, even Joda Time gives up in the parsing of the these kind of timezones...

Comment: You could try `parse(dateString.replace("LST", "BRST"));`

Comment: In the end this is what I did: `dateString = dateString.replaceFirst("...$", "GMT");` and then do the parsing

Comment: While that will parse, it will make your time "GMT" instead of the time in Brazil.

Comment: I know, but I am afraid this issue is not only for a Brazil timezone, I immagine having the same difficulty with Russia, China, Africa, etc... I need something that works with unpredicted or ambiguous values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My current workaround is:

```
// Date to parse
String dateString = "Tue, 06 Nov 2012 5:30 pm LST";

// This parser works with some timezones but fails with ambiguous ones...
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy h:mm a zzz");

Date date = null;  
try {
    // Try to parse normally
    date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // Failed, try to parse with a GMT timezone as a workaround.
    // Replace the last 3 characters with "GMT"
    dateString = dateString.replaceFirst("...$", "GMT");
    // Parse again
    date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-02:00");
gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTime);

System.out.println("Brazil :: " + gmtFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: Why you put GMT-02:00 and not just GMT?

Comment: @erasmospunk: that is because GMT-02:00 specifies the time zone for Brazil. For more info on timezone refer this link [TimeZone Explained](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)

Comment: the code that doesn't work posted in my question. The before and after stuff are irrelevant. I have the `dateString` as the input and I need the `date` as the output